# Why is the error occurring during the tensorflow verification?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

The error occured during verification of the tensorflow code 'python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"'. The code is also available on official website of tensorflow: tensorflow.org/install/pip. I also tried the wheel file from https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/tree/master/1.13.1/py37

```
(venv) C:\Users\Tila>python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_exe
cution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tila\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_t
ensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Tila\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_t
ensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Tila\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_t
ensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, descript
ion)
  File "C:\Users\Tila\venv\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Tila\venv\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Tila\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", l
ine 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-im
port
  File "C:\Users\Tila\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__
.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Tila\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_t
ensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tila\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_t
ensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Tila\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_t
ensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Tila\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_t
ensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, descript
ion)
  File "C:\Users\Tila\venv\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Tila\venv\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: What is the code that generated the error(s)? What other details can you provide?

Comment: The error occured during verification of the tensorflow code 'python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"'. The code is also available on official website of tensorflow: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Comment: Does your processor support AVX instructions? If not download the TF wheel file from here ~> https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel

Comment: Tried the wheel but having issues with 1.13.1 wheel file.